# Schema data on inner page

Tags: seo, schema.org, google-rich-snippets

I have a website and I'm beginning to add schema tags to it. One worry I have is having schema data only inside subpages.

My reviews page is located under /testimonials and the schema data works perfectly as tested in Googles schema rich snippets tool.

However, these reviews don't appear anywhere on the home page, so the review schema is NOT appearing on the home page. Should I add them hidden on the home page in the HTML so that they're picked up, or is there a way to tell Google that my reviews page is located at /testimonials?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Google’s handling/interpretation of Schema.org / SEO. It might be on-topic on [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, no, you should never hide your schemas.  That goes against Google's guidelines and they will just ignore your markups.  Secondly, a homepage is typically not a good place to mark up reviews and ratings, because the markups should be indicative of the main content on the page and because the page should also include a mechanism to gather and post customer reviews.  So again, without that mechanism, Google won't trust your review markups.

So my advice would be to create a strong testimonials page that includes your business' reviews and ratings along with a system to gather and post them to that page.  If you mark them up well and structure your markups correctly (don't trust Google's testing tool to notify you of all errors), Google may very well display a rating rich snippet for that page.  And with good SEO, you can have both pages appearing on the first page of Google for relevant search queries, with rich snippets.